# Late binding issue with MVC3 ViewBag in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I'm trying out MVC Scaffolding in a VB.NET MVC3 project and running into an issue with late binding with Option Strict set on (and I want it on).

This works in C#:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.PossibleTeams = context.Teams;
    return View();
}
```

but the virtually the same code in VB.NET:

```
Public Function Create() As ActionResult
    ViewBag.PossibleTeams = context.Teams
    Return View()
End Function
```

causes the compiler error *Option Strict On disallows late binding*.  I took a look at the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(VS.98).aspx but it wasn't very helpful.

I notice that a new empty application in C# uses the `ViewBag` in the `HomeController` but the VB.NET version uses `ViewData`, so maybe this is a VB.NET limitation.

Comment: I just created a new VB.Net project using the Internet Application template for MVC4 RC and it used the ViewBag property. It did not build until I replaced it with ViewData.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not a Trust issue. Option Strict On disallows late binding. In VB.Net, use the ViewData object instead and maintain your Option Strict On setting.

Comment: Given the templates used ViewData I reckoned this must be the case so that's what I've been using.

Answer (score 0):

The mayor problem with `ViewBag` in VB (and the reason why the VB template uses `ViewData`) is that the VB binder does not work with things typed as dynamic in medium trust. Try setting your app to full trust.

Comment: I changed the web.config file to Full Trust but it's not making any difference to the compile time error. I haven't had trust issues before, so this would be a new avenue for me.